# Perfectly functioning anchor tags on desktop Chrome suddenly unclickable on Android Chrome browser?

Tags: android, google-chrome, hyperlink, anchor, broken-links

I have a problem with two (probably) interrelated issues. The navigation bar I created for my friend's website contains anchor tags that link to element IDs within the page. All of these anchor tags (except for one which exists outside of the navigation bar) correctly take the user who clicks on them to their respective page elements, and this works on (desktop) Chrome, Brave, Edge, and Safari (as far as know). The problem is that they (except the one outside the navigation bar) are completely unclickable on my Android's Chrome browser. The anchor tag not included in my navigation bar is only clickable after certain conditions (i.e. it's the first link clicked or nothing else is "focused" on the page), otherwise it too is malfunctioning.

There is no JavaScript connected to these links whatsoever and the syntax looks perfectly correct from where I see (`<a href="#aboutMe" aria-label="Learn more about Jake">About Me</a>`. I'm not sure how to remedy this situation or what might be causing this behavior.

To reiterate, I tried making navigation links that scroll the user to different page elements. They work perfectly everywhere because that's really simple, but they don't work as expected on the Android Chrome browser. They become unclickable entirely or only under certain conditions (which are not defined by me). I reviewed all of the actual HTML and everything should work.